# Feature of zooming in hat

Tags: discussion, winter-bash-2016

I received this hat:

[image]

But on going to control on the hat, it shows only two controls:

1. Rotation
2. Positioning.

Suggestion:

Allow users to resize the hat.

Comment: Suggestion: Please have someone proof-read your posts. It's "hat", not "hate".

Comment: @Cerbrus not understand what you say can you clarify.

Comment: Take a look at my edits. Your question was full of grammatical mistakes. I don't usually call out people on grammar like this, but at very least use a spell checker.

Comment: @Cerbrus Thanks for your edit and knowledge Next time I try my best.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

They are actually resizable, look:

[image]